# Regarding user settings - whats the purpose of the assets folder?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I want to find the correct place to save my user settings for my uwp app. I know there exists:

- local: Data that exists on the current device and is backed up in the cloud
- roaming: Data that exists on all devices on which the user has installed the app
- temporary: Data that could be removed by the system any time the app isn't running 
  -localcache: Persistent data that
  exists only on the current device

I can access the above places with `ApplicationData.Current`. Which are located somewhere in `C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Packages\1e7e-94a6-4235-a0c5-9b143f8b_8webbwe`

The project also contains a Asset folder, and I can't find a good source which tells me where the folder is located when the app is installed (not in developer mode).

Some developers place there settings into the asset folder. Why? What's the advantage? Is there also a file size limit like for `ApplicationData.Current` ? When deploying a settings folder into the asset folder will it be available for all user which installed my app? Any background informations regarding the asset folder are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings files are most appropriate in the ApplicationData folders or ApplicationData.[LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) or .[RoamingSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx) See [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx)

The assets folder is purely a convention. The "assets" name is not special other than to suggest what types of files go in the folder. It is just a useful way to organize the application package to have a place for assets (images, etc.) that are used in the app.

When the app is installed the assets will be in the [Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) directory and can be addressed with an ms-appx:///assets/ URI. Typically this will end up somewhere in \Program Files\WindowsApps\.

Putting a settings file in assets would be a bad idea as the InstalledLocation is read-only and as settings are user data.

There is no hard size limit for files in ApplicationData folders, although if too much data is stored in RoamingFolder then it won't roam. The files will still be available locally.